# How many $\rm eV$ near Fermi level are involved to the conduction of carriers? For metal and degernerated semiconductors?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, fermi-energy

How many $\rm eV$ near Fermi level are involved to the conduction of carriers? For metal and degernerated semiconductors?  Someone say about ± 5 eV, but I cannot find any references to support.

Answer (score 3):

Conduction electrons are the ones within a window $k_B T$ around $E_F$. This is because thermal broadening of the Fermi function (at finite temperatures) create higher energy states that electrons can be excited into.

At room temperature (300K) : $\Delta E = k_B T = 0.023 eV$

For further reading I recommend "Quantum Transport" by Beenakker.

Comment: Welcome! Nice answer, clear and concise.

Comment: Thank you Gilbert!

Comment: Thank you very much!  It really helps, let me check the reference~. By the way, I find this place is wonderful~lol.

Answer (score 1):

The Fermi distribution approaches, but never reaches, zero. Therefore there can be carriers of any arbitrary distance form the Fermi level limited only by the material's density of states.

The Fermi distribution does quickly approach zero though, especially at low temperatures. So you will need to decide what probability of occupation is sufficiently small for you to not consider, and your temperature. With this info it is trivial to calculate the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You answer give me hints on my question !